# Highlight Multiple Input ID's on javascript validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

using javascript validation and some jquery to show variable error messages in the DOM, and highlighting both the form label and field.

For this particular error message, I need to highlight 2 fields (email1 and email2).
Unsure how to add it to my current setup for alerts below:

```
customAlert ("email2",bnadd_msg_022);
```

simple question, how to I add email1 into the mix?

Edit:

Here is my jquery function:

```
function customAlert(inputID,msg){

      $("li").removeClass("alertRed");
      $("input").removeClass("CO_form_alert");  
      $("select").removeClass("CO_form_alert");   
      var div = $(".errorPopup");
      div.css({"display":"block"});
      $("#"+inputID).addClass("CO_form_alert").parent().addClass("alertRed");
      if (div.length == 0) {
        div = $("<div class='errorPopup' onclick='$(this).hide();'></div>");
        $("body").prepend(div);
      } 
      div.html(msg);
      $("#"+inputID).focus(function(){
        $(this).unbind('focus'); // remove this handler
        $('.errorPopup').hide(); // hide error popup
   });
```

So, In this case and on one other, I need to highlight 2 fields simultaneously

Comment: It's going to depend on what that "customAlert()" function looks like.

Comment: If you can post the simple HTML and JS you will get better answers

Comment: @Pointy @Bobby Borszich - see edit above. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make use of the arguments 'array' in Javascript, and simply define customAlert as a function with no arguments.

```
function customAlert(){
    var args = arguments;
    if(args.length > 1) {
        // check that custom alert was called with at least two arguments
        var msg = args[0];
        $("li").removeClass("alertRed");
        $("input").removeClass("CO_form_alert");  
        $("select").removeClass("CO_form_alert");   
        var div = $(".errorPopup");
        div.css({"display":"block"});
        if (div.length == 0) {
            div = $("<div class='errorPopup' onclick='$(this).hide();'></div>");
            $("body").prepend(div);
        } 
        div.html(msg);
        for(var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            var inputID = args[i];
           $("#"+inputID).addClass("CO_form_alert").parent().addClass("alertRed");
            $("#"+inputID).focus(function(){
                $(this).unbind('focus'); // remove this handler
                $('.errorPopup').hide(); // hide error popup
            });
        }
     }
}
```

Then you call it like so:

```
customAlert(bnadd_msg_022,"email2"); // note the order of the arguments has changed
customAlert(bnadd_msg_022,"email1","email2");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with the above code the highlighting of the label and form field is no longer present - specifically addClass - CO_form_alert and alertRed

Comment: @Jason I missed that line in the code - I'll update the answer to include it in the for loop.

Comment: beautiful. Worked like a charm. I appreciate the help. I'm in process of learning jquery and javascript more thoroughly (most of what I know is related to front end development, visual effects, etc.) so I appreciate the knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, my guess is that you could change the customAlert function to take an optional third argument.

The way I would do it is make that third argument an array that can accept n number of field id's. In the customAlert function, I would check to see if the argument is passed, and if so loop through the array and highlight any id that is included therein.

Comment: This would probably work, assuming the single msg argument would suffice.